# Is there any method similar to toXMLString() in pycrypto RSA?

Tags: c#, python, encryption, pycrypto

I know in C# `RSACryptoServiceProvider` has [ToXmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that supports exporting the n and e values in base64(?) format in a XML file. I am using PyCrypto RSA modules's [RSA.generate](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html) to create a new key.

I am aware that there is a `exportKey()` function and currently I can save it in PEM format. Saving it in PEM format gives me something as follows:

MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCfGtS6zBwWeXWelsSOhG1/pe40
goxMGHe9bb1UBtKBAjhi00ZKxwygM5cbTj+k1+wNaIi64UpE8ixOfRY9hVUpYZ1r
QP/Ox8rWyvqdKW6FTm9PIUz4chrbyjgTUENWdfk9Nl6GJ1ZyeN49z4j4QavFBxe9
h+VkLc91hr7MHbq53QIDAQAB

Out of which, last 4 characters AQAB seems like the base64 representation for 65537 which is the exponent. But if I interpret the rest of the pem except AQAB as base64 representation of modulus then I end up with decode error.

I attempted to use `struct.pack` to convert the n(modulus) to bytes for getting a base64 representation but I end up with a overflow. n is really big, I am not sure what data type is it:

1117271960777822123914386767255132691236470141330742633576958345789905066768642795553191088144426491796396398212407134324451       3691835386930230821948992495529518257623152363611603952277356641370464835962436639078429958826695573074110215764561518716014                                    9223488427614600372039517756352143348068193387291216981965277

Is there any way to convert the modulus and exponent of public key created by PyCrypto RSA module to ToXmlString functionality?

Comment: Use `_RSAobj.keydata` and generate the XML manually.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin is the key supposed to be base64 encoded? The key is really long so I am not sure how to convert it to byte and then base64 encode it?